# Mount a network folder on Linux system Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, mount

I just mount a network folder on Linux system , and we are using the folder on the folder by using RStudio . But from RStudio we can see all of the filers (can Read) But we can not Write .

```
bash-4.2$ echo "ttt" > abc_test.txt
bash: abc_test.txt: Permission denied
```

I can write on login to Linux server but not from the RStudio.

By investigate I found , file permissions has been change .

Before Mount :

```
drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 4096 May 6 07:26 CounterfeitPartIPT
```

After Mount :

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Jun 8 19:34 CounterfeitPartIPT
```

What will be the solution ? How can I write on the share file ?

Comment: "_I just mount a network folder on Linux system_" - how did you do this? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/706188/edit) to show us the actual command you used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `chown -R *yourusername*:*yourusernameorgroupifyouhaveone* /path/to/mnt` on the mount point of your network share. If the network share uses NFS, you might need to explicitly set the uid and gid in /etc/fstab, the -o flag of the mount command, or the /etc/export on the server.

Comment: We don't know if it's NFS, Samba, or one of the other network file system types

Comment: And you should also note that before and after mounting, there are acl's against it, hence the `'.'` at the end of the permissions.